# Python MemoryError when I use the request API call

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm writing a very simple program to pull the prices for specific AWS services (in my example, Amazon EC2) using the AWS Price List API.

My simple function, price_list(), is where my code is breaking.

```
def price_list(self):
    response = requests.get("https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json")
    pricing = response.json()
    print(pricing)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
MemoryError
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

P.S. I'm using Python 3.

Comment: The data you are requesting is likely too big for the memory on the machine

Comment: curl --head https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json said that Content-Length is 1 333 489 455 bytes or 1.24 GB

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've run out of available memory:

```py
r = requests.head("https://pricing.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/offers/v1.0/aws/AmazonEC2/current/index.json")
r.headers['Content-Length']  # 1333489455 bytes
```